# Android PATCH request using Volley

Tags: android, android-volley

I spend hours on this issue,

I'm trying to send a PATCH request using Volley with OkHttp (as PATCH request are not working on pre-Lollipop...)

I've follow this link

[enter link description here](https://gist.github.com/JakeWharton/5616899)

Now I can see my request working but as a POST request !

```
mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mCtx.getApplicationContext(), new OkHttpStack());
```

When I log in addToRequestQueue(Request req) my request is well set as 7 which means PATCH and it is the "last point" before sending the request...

Txs a lot for help :)

Comment: Your code there just creates a request queue.  You're complaining about it using the wrong verb.  You need to give us the code used to create the request.

Comment: Txs for the answer! I'm extending  Request<T> passing Method.PATCH to the constructor super(method, url, errorListener);

Sorry I dont post the code as I have extending my request and it will add a lot of extra code.

The thing is that the method seems to be well created as when I call addToRequestQueue my request is well set to PATCH...

Comment: "Sorry I dont post the code as I have extending my request and it will add a lot of extra code" -- then create some other project that reproduces the problem, that you can use as part of a [mcve] with the code and complete stack trace. Creating [a duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42179609/115145), with even less information than you have here, is not a solution. Volley is not designed for arbitrary HTTP requests; IMHO you are better served using OkHttp directly.